# OLS estimator of a non-linear trend regression

Tags: regression, self-study, econometrics, trend

I'm trying to find the OLS estimator $\hat{\beta}$ of the following model:

$$Y_t = \beta t^{(3/2)}+\epsilon_t~~~~~~~~, ~ \epsilon \sim NID(0, \sigma^2)$$

So I started in this way. Firts the sum of squares function is:

$$S(\hat{B})  = \sum_{t=1}^n (Y_t - \beta t^{(3/2)})^2 \\
= \sum_{t=1}^n (Y_t^2-2Y_t\beta t^{3/2}+\beta^2t^3)$$

Then I took the first derivative of it:

$$\dfrac{ \partial S(\hat{\beta})}{\partial \hat{\beta}}=-2\sum_{t=1}^n (Y_tt^{3/2}-\beta t^3)$$

Then I equal it to zero to find the condition of the first order:

$$-2\sum_{t=1}^n (Y_tt^{3/2}-\beta t^3) = 0$$

Reached this point I am not able to continue. Have I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When we speak of a *linear* model, what we are assuming is that it is linear in the *parameters*. This is the case for your model, and the usual OLS estimator is correct.

If you want to continue with your derivation, you can divide out by -2 and split the sum like this:

$$\sum_{t=1}^n Y_t t^{3/2} = \beta \sum_{t=1}^n t^3$$

Then divide to find that:

$$\hat{\beta} = \frac{\sum_{t=1}^n Y_t t^{3/2}}{\sum_{t=1}^n t^3}$$

If you define $X_t = t^{3/2}$, then this is just:

$$\hat{\beta} = \frac{\sum_{t=1}^n Y_t X_t}{\sum_{t=1}^n X_t^2}$$

This is the usual OLS solution when there is no intercept.

Comment: Many thanks... from this point how is it possible to derive the distribution of this estimator? In particular the expected value and the variance?

Comment: Yes, simply refer to the usual properties of the OLS estimator, and plug in $X_t = t^{3/2}$ as needed.

Comment: I need to see the passages, moreover I would like the solution without the trick of $X_t = t^{3/2}$. I'm going to open a new question answer there if you want.